# Reduce malloc calls by slicing one big malloc'd memory

Tags: c, memory, malloc, dynamic-allocation

First, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2079151/minimizing-the-amount-of-malloc-calls-improves-performance) is where I got the idea from:

> There was once an app I wrote that used lots of little blobs of
>   memory, each allocated with malloc(). It worked correctly but was
>   slow. I replaced the many calls to malloc with just one, and then
>   sliced up that large block within my app. It was much much faster.

I was profiling my application, and I got a unexpectedly nice performance boost when I reduced the number of malloc calls. I am still allocating the same amount of memory, though.

So, I would like to do what this guy did, but I am unsure what's the best way to do it.

**My Idea:**

```
// static global variables
static void * memoryForStruct1 = malloc(sizeof(Struct1) * 10000);
int struct1Index = 0;
...
// somewhere, I need memory, fast:
Struct1* data = memoryForStruct1[struct1Index++];
...
// done with data:
--struct1Index;
```

**Gotchas:**

- I have to make sure I don't exceed 10000
- I have to release the memory in the same order I occupied. (Not a major issue in my case, since I am using recursion, but I would like to avoid it if possible).

---

**Inspired from Mihai Maruseac:**

First, I create a linked list of `int` that basically tells me which memory indexes are free. I then added a property to my struct called `int memoryIndex` which helps me return the memory occupied in any order. And Luckily, I am sure my memory needs would never exceed 5 MB at any given time, so I can safely allocate that much memory. Solved.

Comment: That can be very useful.  It can save both time and space if you have certain allocation behavior that you can take advantage of.  For example, if you know your memory usage is stack-like, or that you always need chunks of the same size.  The best way to handle it depends on these requirements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The system call which gives you memory is `brk`. The usual `malloc` and `calloc`, `realloc` functions simply use the space given by `brk`. When that space is not enough, another `brk` is made to create new space. Usually, the space is increased in sizes of a virtual memory page.

Thus, if you really want to have a premade pool of objects, then make sure to allocate memory in multiples of pagesize. For example, you can create one pool of `4KB`. `8KB`, ... space.

Next idea, look at your objects. Some of them have one size, some have other size. It will be a big pain to handle allocations for all of them from the same pool. Create pools for objects of various sizes (powers of 2 is best) and allocate from them. For example, if you'll have an object of size `34B` you'd allocate space for it from the `64B` pool.

Lastly, the remaining space can be either left unused or it can be moved down to the other pools. In the above example, you have `30B` left. You'd split it in `16B`, `8B`, `4B` and `2B` chunks and add each chunk to their respective pool.

Thus, you'd use linked lists to manage the preallocated space. Which means that your application will use more memory than it actually needs but if this really helps you, why not?

Basically, what I've described is a mix between [buddy allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buddy_memory_allocation) and [slab allocator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Slab_allocation) from the Linux kernel.

**Edit**: After reading your comments, it will be pretty easy to allocate a big area with `malloc(BIG_SPACE)` and use this as a pool for your memory.

Comment: I really like your explanation, but I can't figure out how to use it? Should I somehow allocate a large memory through `brk`, then malloc calls will be faster by taking that space?

Comment: Btw, I only have objects of one size. So, it should be very simple. I would like to use your linked list idea, but I can't figure that one, too.

Comment: No, `brk` was just to show that not `malloc` is taking the time. Doing 10 `malloc`s of 1KB is the same as doing 3 `malloc`s of 4KB.

Comment: For single larger allocations, often `mmap` is used instead of `brk`.

Answer (score 1):

If you can, look at using [glib](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) which has [memory slicing API](http://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Memory-Slices.html) that supports this. It's very easy to use, and saves you from having to re-implement it.